# Render components conditionally after unsuccessful results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

My previous question led me here and after being able to access and use musixmatch API successfully, I now see that not all the songs have lyrics.

So I'm getting the songs but they are some songs that don't have their lyrics published yet and I want to handle this error.
I first set the lyrics to `setLyrics`, then check if its undefined and use a spinner to load and then disappear when the fetch returns results.

```
return trackInfo ===undefined||lyrics===undefined ||Object.keys(trackInfo).length===0 
       ||Object.keys(lyrics).length===0 ? 
       <Spinner/>:<Songlyrics/>
```

but what if the resource never comes because it doesn't exist, the spinner just keeps loading indefinitely, I want the spinner to load for a few seconds but if there are no lyrics for a particular song, render a component that tells the user that the resource isn't available and reroute to the home page.

I have tried using a `setTimeout` but now even if the lyric is available I'm still rerouted which tells me I'm missing something, I also need to figure out a way to render the `noLyrics` message component.

```
    return trackInfo ===undefined||lyrics===undefined ||Object.keys(trackInfo).length===0 ||Object.keys(lyrics).length===0 ? 
         <>
          <Spinner/>
          setTimeout(()=>{
            navigate('/')
},6000)
         </>
:<Songlyrics/>
```

Can someone help me?
For more context:

```
function Lyrics() {
    const [lyrics,setLyrics]=useState('')
    const [loading,setLoading]=useState(false)

    const navigate =useNavigate()
    // get request for lyrics by id
    useEffect(()=>{
         setLoading(true)
      fetch('getting lyrics')
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(data=>{
            // setLyric to the lyric body
             setLoading(false)
            setLyrics(data.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body)
        })
    
    },[])
      
     

  return loading ? <Spinner/>:
  (trackInfo ===undefined||lyrics===undefined ||Object.keys(trackInfo).length===0 ||Object.keys(lyrics).length===0?<DoesNotExist/>
  :
  (
    <component/>
  )
)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you determine from your state data whether the value is missing because it's still loading or whether the value is missing because it doesn't exist?  That would be the condition to check.

If there's currently no way to infer that information, add a state value for it.  For example, you could have something like:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```

And in your markup:

```
{
  isLoading ? <Spinner/> :
  (/* the rest of your logic, conditionally determining if the value exists or not */)
}
```

Then you'd simply update `isLoading` when starting or completing any given API call for that operation.  If there are multiple simultaneous calls, you'd need multiple values.  (Maybe a state value for each, maybe an array of which calls are currently loading, that's really up to you.)

However you design it, overall the main point is that currently you have two states:

1. Value exists
2. Value doesn't exist

But you need three states:

1. Value exists
2. Value doesn't exist because it's still being fetched
3. Value doesn't exist after completing the fetch

Comment: so I just implemented the set loading in my API call, false by default, true when fetching and false when fetched, that's 2 use cases(still fetching and fetched) , but how do I do the "value doesn't exist after completing fetch" logic?

Comment: if its not too much trouble, could you elaborate further?

Comment: @Lucid: That's essentially the logic you already have.  For example (in somewhat pseudo-code), if `fetching == true && lyrics == undefined` then the value is being fetched, but if `fetching == false && lyrics == undefined` then the value was already fetched but there was no data.

Comment: return loading ? <Spinner/>:
  (trackInfo ===undefined|| lyrics===undefined ||Object.keys(trackInfo).length===0 ||Object.keys(lyrics).length===0?<DoesNotExist/>
  :
  (<componentThatExist/>)

Comment: @Lucid: At a glance that looks reasonable.  You can think of it like a nested `if`.  The outer `if` is "loading" vs. "not loading".  And within the "not loading" segment is the inner `if` of "data is there" vs. "data is not there".

Comment: it works1!!, songs that don't have lyrics render the <DoesNotExist/> component, but now for songs that have lyrics, the <DoesNotExist/> components render for a split second and then get the lyrics, why is it like this and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Lucid: It sounds like the default "loading" state is `false` in that case.  So on the first render it doesn't think it's loading.  Generally I set the default to `true` if I know that the component is going to immediately try to load the data.  I only set it to `false` if the data will be loaded at some later time, such as after user input.  (And if that's the case then you may need to define additional state data to differentiate between "not loading yet" and "loading".)

Comment: my API request doesn't run on fetch on page load, it takes input in a search bar and fetches and returns results when I click search

Comment: @Lucid: Could be.  Without a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the issue all I can do is guess.  But anything that happens "for a split second" when loading a React component is, 99% of the time, state that is immediately changing from its default to something else.

Comment: check my question again , i just updated it with more context, let me know if its enough

Comment: Previously you'd indicated that the default state for `loading` was `true` in your code.  It isn't: `const [loading,setLoading]=useState(false)`  It looks like you've replaced that comment with one indicating that the API request isn't made when the component loads.  But your `useEffect` indicates otherwise.  Generally I set the default to `true` if I know that the component is going to immediately try to load the data. I only set it to `false` if the data will be loaded at some later time, such as after user input.

Comment: just fixed that but I'm still getting that split-second rendering b4 my component renders